# Could I have an undetected deadlock?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, deadlock

Upon running `sp_whoisactive` on a server for the first time, I was greeted by something unexpected:

[image]

Two sessions had been running for 13 days but both of them seemed to be blocking each other. Taking a look at `sys.dm_tran_locks`:

[image]

The configuration value for the blocked process threshold setting is 10 seconds.  Other deadlocks are being successfully resolved on the server via the deadlock monitor.

Information from the `@get_locks` parameter:

```
<Database name="DB1">
  <Locks>
    <Lock request_mode="S" request_status="GRANT" request_count="1" />
  </Locks>
  <Objects>
    <Object name="TBL1" schema_name="dbo">
      <Locks>
        <Lock resource_type="OBJECT" request_mode="IX" request_status="GRANT" request_count="1" />
        <Lock resource_type="PAGE" page_type="*" index_name="PK__TBL1__3214EC27326C5B6A" request_mode="U" request_status="GRANT" request_count="1" />
        <Lock resource_type="PAGE" page_type="*" index_name="PK__TBL1__3214EC27326C5B6A" request_mode="U" request_status="WAIT" request_count="1" />
      </Locks>
    </Object>
  </Objects>
</Database>


<Database name="DB1">
    <Locks>
        <Lock request_mode="S" request_status="GRANT" request_count="1" />
    </Locks>
    <Objects>
        <Object name="TBL2" schema_name="dbo">
            <Locks>
                <Lock resource_type="OBJECT" request_mode="Sch-S" request_status="GRANT" request_count="2" />
            </Locks>
        </Object>
        <Object name="TBL1" schema_name="dbo">
            <Locks>
                <Lock resource_type="OBJECT" request_mode="IX" request_status="GRANT" request_count="5" />
                <Lock resource_type="PAGE" page_type="*" index_name="PK__TBL1__3214EC27326C5B6A" request_mode="U" request_status="GRANT" request_count="33701" />
                <Lock resource_type="PAGE" page_type="*" index_name="PK__TBL1__3214EC27326C5B6A" request_mode="U" request_status="WAIT" request_count="1" />
            </Locks>
        </Object>
    </Objects>
</Database>
```

I've occasionally seen the term "undetected deadlock" but I don't have any direct experience with them. My questions are:

1. Could this be an example of an undetected deadlock? I can't see how the situation gets resolved without intervention from the deadlock monitor thread, but for some reason that hasn't happened yet.
2. Is there anything to do other than update to the latest CU and hope the issue doesn't occur again? The server is currently on 2017 CU10 which I know is a bit out of date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a [comment](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/299736/could-i-have-an-undetected-deadlock#comment585383_299736) left by [David Browne - Microsoft](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/126936/david-browne-microsoft)

> "Undetected deadlocks" usually means "undetectable deadlocks", eg where session is blocked by a SQL Server lock, and the other is blocked in the client application, or where a session calls `xp_cmdshell` which a runs a program that connects to the database and becomes blocked by the session waiting on the completion of `xp_cmdshell`.  Having an *ordinary* deadlock not resolved automatically looks like a bug.